# Jumble mini-flail: is this balanced?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, balance, homebrew-review

The jumble mini-flail is a mix of materials that:

- All-together causes 1d2 lethal damage & 1d2 non-lethal damage (yes you read that right).
- For every 2 hours searching a warzone or battleground or paying 25 gp/die increase or criticle upgrade you can up it 1 die type up to 1d12; after that it increases critical (normally ×2) by one type up to ×4.
- Each month you must do the same search of a warzone or battle ground or pay the same price as above or the flail goes down one die type/critical until it reaches its base stats.
- If you add special materials to the jumble mini-flail then it has a 25% chance of cutting through a creature natural defenses.
- Enchantments cannot be added to this weapon.

This weapon is a one-handed weapon, and it's a simple weapon due to it's simple construction that can be adjusted to the users preferences.

Is this weapon balanced?

Comment: The addition of the picture is both large and unhelpful as it raises more questions than it answers.

Comment: The question is asking if your stats are balanced, which doesn't need us to know what you were going for. The only reason we would need to know that is if the question were asking us to stat up your idea for you, which the question is not asking. (And may I remind you, we have said explicitly RPG.se will not stat up your ideas for you.) I've removed the irrelevant image.

Comment: Editing the question two years after the fact to apply an order-of-magnitude change to the costs of the thing is *quite* dubious; please see [our guidance on homebrew iteration in response to critique](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8010/4563). I have rolled back that edit.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because you shouldn't  correct mistakes in your question that were already corrected by answers because it invalidates them.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the exception of only the very earliest levels, it’s a complete waste of time and money. Its inability to accept magic and its unreliability in the face of damage reduction makes it not worth using at all.

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with the upkeep issue—a month is extremely long time for an adventurer, and 25 gp is an extremely small amount of money. 350 gp upgrades this weapon as far as it can go, and that’s chump change, particularly on a per-month basis. A 1st level character cannot afford that—but an adventurer doesn’t stay 1st level for a whole month, either. Under the default guidelines, a month of adventuring is enough to gain approximately **nine** levels (an average of 4 encounters per day, approximately 13 encounters per level-up, per *Dungeon Master’s Guide* pg. 41). A 10th level character might very well not bother to track gold pieces in units smaller than 1,000 gp.

However, *for a 1st-level character*, upgrading it once and using it until enemies start demanding magic weaponry (at best, 5th level, but probably more like 3rd—long before the weapon begins to degrade) isn’t just a reasonable option: it’s the *clearly best option*. No weapon in the game deals that much damage, much less a simple one-handed one.

So basically, no, it’s not balanced; either you need magic too much and you can’t use it, or you don’t and it’s overpowered.

To make a workable weapon, it needs to be compatible with magic (and it needs to work better with special materials; a 25% chance to pierce is not useful), but then its damage is much too high. For a weird, *ad hoc* weapon, the simple category isn’t appropriate at all—flails are difficult to use, and this one is even more so since it’s not well made. This has all the hallmarks of an exotic weapon—unique mechanics, bizarre description, potential for upsides.

However, even as a magic-compatible exotic weapon, the upkeep mechanic has serious problems. The numbers you can get are very, very good: it provides somewhere in the neighborhood of a +8 bonus to damage. Power Attack cannot match that for several levels, and then only with a two-hander and accepting a −4 penalty. That’s a huge bonus for caring about upkeep—which is typically below 3.5’s abstraction threshold. Upkeep happens in the background. Players can bring it more into the foreground if it interests them, but getting a bonus for doing so, particularly one this large, *forces* players to do so. Including those who are not interested in doing so, and will find it unfun interacting with the weapon's upkeep mechanic (but do it anyway, because they must).

A better solution for a weapon that is gradually built up by combing battlefields would be one that scales with character level. Then an Exotic Weapon Proficiency feat can be directly compared with Power Attack to balance it. This is far more in keeping with 3.5’s design and makes the option far more amenable to comparison and balancing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47265/discussion-between-kryan-and-abraham-ray).

Answer (score 7):

No, this weapon is too powerful. Here is the greatest problem: you've assumed that a 25gp upgrade cost is significant, but for adventurers after first level, they'll easily have enough money to upgrade it to max level.

Most simple one-handed weapons do a base of 1d6 damage, which is 3.5 on average. After upgrades, this weapon does a base of 2d12, which is 13 on average -- more than three times as good.

You've tried to balance this weapon by saying that it can't be enchanted, but that's not a good restriction: it makes the weapon unusably bad for very high-level characters and still way too good for low-level characters. Medium-level characters would likely still consider this weapon really good, they'd just have to carry a few backup weapons (silver longsword, magic longsword, etc) in case they ran into something with lots of DR.

Also, I think it's weird that you've described this as a "simple" weapon. Simple weapons are usually used by non-fighter characters who don't use the weapon as their primary damage source and don't want to think about it too much. That's not the sort of character that I envision using this weapon.

Here is a variant that is closer to being balanced: it is an exotic weapon, and it cannot be upgraded for money. To upgrade this weapon the first time, you must spend ten minutes salvaging the newly defeated corpse of a CR1 (or greater) opponent. The second upgrade requires ten minutes and a CR2 opponent, and so on. The weapon always has an x3 critical rating, but it loses an upgrade each time it confirms a crit.